# curl -L not working on openSUSE Issue with Certificate

Tags: opensuse, curl, certificates

For some strange reason I can't execute `curl -L https://github.com/Blosc/c-blosc/archive/v1.8.1.tar.gz`. I need it for some package installation of `Blosc` that utilizes `curl`.

I get the error:

```
curl: (77) Error reading ca cert file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt - mbedTLS: (-0x3E00) PK - Read/write of file failed
```

So there is not cert in the location. Fine. So I converted my ca-bundle.pem from `/etc/ssl` into .crt and copied it to that location.

Now I get:

```
url: (51) Cert verify failed: BADCERT_NOT_TRUSTED
```

Great. I read something about the `update-ca-trust` tool, but that doesn't seem to be installed on openSUSE 42.1 Leap. So I could add the cert to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/` and update. Anyhow why is it not trusted. Its already there. Or do I need to create a new one in YAST?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with not verifying the remote certificate and you just want to download the tarball, you can use the "insecure connection" flag (`-k` or `--insecure`):

```
curl -Lk https://github.com/Blosc/c-blosc/archive/v1.8.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this as a temporary solution. Still it would be nice to resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution which works...; 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1OA32717

Load cert to some place with some name, set env which point to it..;
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE='/root/cacert.pem'